# How to stop click event in ngDraggable angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a few draggable panels with links. I want to stop the click event when drag them. Every time when I drop the tile, it goes to the address. I use ngDraggable.js .  I tried to use e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() but no luck.

```
angular.module('ExampleApp', ['ngDraggable']).
        controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.draggableObjects = [
                {name: 'one'},
                {name: 'two'},
                {name: 'three'}
            ];
            $scope.onDropComplete = function (index, obj, evt) {
                var otherObj = $scope.draggableObjects[index];
                var otherIndex = $scope.draggableObjects.indexOf(obj);
                $scope.draggableObjects[index] = obj;
                $scope.draggableObjects[otherIndex] = otherObj;
                evt.stopPropagation();
                evt.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

html

```
<div class="row text-center" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul class="draglist">
    <li ng-repeat="obj in draggableObjects" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete($index, $data,$event)">
        <div ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj" ng-class="obj.name">
            {{obj.name}}
        </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to be sure, have you added the preventDefault and stopPropagation in the onClick/ng-click right?

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. You hinted to the answer. I was trying to stop click event of the tile, and not the link. Now I set the ng-click to the anchor tag, and in Angular did e.PreventDefault() and it works

Comment: Great! Added the answer, please accept it as correct

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez Only now, I don't know how to fire the click event when need it. :(

Comment: After the event.stopPropagation and event.preventdefault just add the call to your angular function (if you want to call an angular function). If you want to evaluate if you want to stop or not the click event you could make a directive and bind the click event to the directive and inside the directive make the evaluation

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: OR you could add a button/icon with `ng-drag-handle` and let dragging only possible with that button/icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add event.preventDefault and event.stopPropagation in the onClick/ng-click